# Chrome extension double click on a word

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, double-click

I would like to know how to call a function once the user double-clicks on any word on the page they are visiting (from a content script). Something similar to [Google Dictionary extension](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/mgijmajocgfcbeboacabfgobmjgjcoja?hl=en). I have inspected the codes in the extension but it was not indented (compiled/minimized) so I've decided to ask this question here. A snippet of codes would be good. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Exact same question as mine. But it's still a Gold  :-) Thanks Nam.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I suspect Google adds an EventListener to the page to register a double click, and then gets the text that was automatically selected.

http://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener
http://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.getSelection

```
f=function(){
   console.log(window.getSelection().toString());
}
document.body.addEventListener('dblclick',f);
```

Comment: Can you please tell me what is the permission is used for event Listener? It gives me error of undefined