# Running a function in chrome extension on double click/select of a word

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to fire a notification whenever I double click on a word/select it. Found several examples online but I still cannot get my example working:

Manifest:

```
{
  "name": "hh",
  "description": "hh!",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "version": "0.0.0.1",
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [ "http://*/*", "https://*/*" ],
      "js": [ "background.js" ],
      "all_frames": true,
      "run_at": "document_end"
    }
  ],
  "permissions": ["storage", "notifications"],
  "icons": { "128": "neoprice.png" }

}
```

background.js

```
var listener = function(evt) {
    var selection = window.getSelection();
    if (selection.rangeCount > 0) {
        displayPrice();
        var range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
        var text = range.cloneContents().textContent;
        console.log(text);
    }

};
document.addEventListener('dblclick', listener);

function displayPrice(){
  chrome.notifications.create(getNotificationId(), {
    title: "message.data.name",
    iconUrl: 'hh.png',
    type: 'basic',
    message: "message.data.prompt"
  }, function() {});
}

// Returns a new notification ID used in the notification.
function getNotificationId() {
  var id = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9007199254740992) + 1;
  return id.toString();
}
```

I was earlier adding the following but I saw people weren't using it, so I removed it

```
  "app": {
    "background": {
      "scripts": ["background.js", "assets/jquery.min.js"]
  }
 },
```

What I am trying to achieve: Whenever they go to ANY page on selecting a word, it fires the function. Later, I wish to use this for a specific page. :)

Tried: [How to keep the eventlistener real time for chrome extensions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20542340/how-to-keep-the-eventlistener-real-time-for-chrome-extensions)

[Chrome extension double click on a word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007759/chrome-extension-double-click-on-a-word)

https://github.com/max99x/inline-search-chrome-ext

Both don't really work as I want them too. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution

It seems you are confused with [background page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages) and [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts). Your `background.js` is a `content script` in fact, though its name is "background". While [chrome.notifications](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/notifications#method-create) api can be only called in `background page`, trying commenting `displayPrice` function will make your code work.

### Next step

Take a look at above tutorials, w`dblclick` event triggers, use [Message Passing](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) to communicate with background page and call `chrome.notications` api in background page.

### What's more

The following code is used in [chrome apps](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/about_apps) rather than [chrome extension](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions).

```
"app": {
    "background": {
      "scripts": ["background.js", "assets/jquery.min.js"]
    }
 },
```

Comment: thanks, I will look at it. thanks for pointing out my confusion. Just another question, where do I put my displayPrice function then? :/

Comment: @Newbie, in background page (The true background page, you need to declare it in `background` fiels)